# STM32F4 struct unnamed has no field brr

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, hal-library

I'm a newbie to STM32 coding and struggling with the following:

I used to code a little bit with STM32F103C8T6, using cubeMx and HAL libraries.
I made a code using the following code to set the pin to High:

```
   GPIOB->BRR = STEP_Pin;
```

It worked like a charm.

I just try to move my project to an STM32F446RE Nucleo.
I changed a few pieces of my code but I have a compiling error I can't get rid off.

```
../Src/main.c(175): error:  #136: struct "<unnamed>"  has no field "BRR"
```

I have this error for every single line using BRR.
Do you know what I should change?

Config: CubeMx, Keil, HAL Lib, STM32F446RE

Thank you

Comment: STM32F1 and STM32F4 GPIO are fairly different; you may have erroneous references/includes/code to the old target in your code

Comment: If I remember correctly the F4 doesn't come with a BRR definition. Instead you use the BSRR register and to reset a pin you have to shift it by 16. To set a pin you just use the pin directly. Make sure you are including the correct header and you are defining the right device as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BRR Register isn't defined for the GPIOs in the STM32F4 MCUs .You can use BSRR regster instead. for more information see the STM32F4-Reference manual page 286 and also STM32f4xx.h file for the registers have been defined for GPIOs.

Comment: I checked the RM but i'm not sure how to understand it.
As example if i want to set PB5 named DIR; I will send
 GPIOB->BSRR = DIR_Pin;
this is equivalent to:

 GPIOB->BSRR = 0x20; //(bit 5)

When I went to reset, i will have to send:
 GPIOB->BSRR = 0x200000; // (bit 21)

is it correct?

Comment: yes, that's write.